# Description for a verbal tic that is vernacular among young people in the U.S

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, american-english, vernacular

Among teenagers in the U.S., there is currently popular a colloquial way of wrapping up a story:

> bla bla, bla bla (various sentences), so yeah.

The "so yeah" signals that the person is done talking.

I need a term or a phrase to describe this, but more succinctly than I just did.

*What follows is optional reading:*

(Reason I need this: there is a transcript of hearing, with many typos.  In this case, the transcript did not have a typo.  But I am responding to a document in which the author assumed "yeah" was actually a typo, and turned it into "year" in her block quote.  From there, she went on to spin a whole argument based this faulty interpretation.  I was present when the young person was speaking, know him quite well, and am 100% certain he said "yeah," not "year."  My reader will believe me -- that's not a problem -- but space is an issue in what I'm writing.)

**Edit**:

I made a mistake.  It wasn't "so yeah," it was "and yeah."

**Edit #2**: the argument the author spun, and her version of the testimony:

> The student himself agreed that the transfer to School #2 disrupted his school year and negatively impacted his educational performance:
>
> "They're not synched, and so I either have to relearn something or I miss something completely because they weren't taught at -- like, it wasn't taught yet at School #1, but it was already taught at School #2, so I miss a unit, and year."

Comment: @Drew - but I need to explain, succinctly, the function "so, yeah" had in the paragraph. // Note, the slang expression in question is "**so** yeah," not "oh yeah" (which isn't new, but which is used differently).

Comment: yeah-year confusion might exist with a BrE speaker listening to AmE speech or vice versa - is that the case here?

Comment: @JohnFeltz - No, the author was grasping at straws to make her argument.  Here's a description I learned here at ELU of what's going on with the author: *cognitive bias*.  She heard what she wanted to hear.

Comment: Can you just use (sic) for this then?

Comment: @JohnFeltz - No, I have to write a sentence explaining the correction.  It's a key point in the debate.

Comment: @Scott - Won't work.  Summary: With those two words, he is not summarizing what he said in his paragraph.  He's just signalling that he's finished talking about that topic. // Yada etc.: This sounds dismissive of what he said.  Actually he explained something quite important.

Comment: Oh, you mean he didn't *actually* say "bla bla, bla bla"? You might want to research techniques for quoting versus reporting speech.

Comment: @Scott - I could give you the whole paragraph but I think that would just muddy the waters.  It was several sentences long.

Comment: “So yeah” is quite common with my daughter and her friends and i’ve always taken it to mean various things in context like: “so that’s what I know about it” or “so that will corroborate what someone else just said” or “so yes I agree” or “so yes, that happened” or “so you can draw your own conclusion” (and then the “yeah” is just a filler because they don’t have anything else to say.). Or similarly “so, anyway” (a mild attempt to change the subject) ...

Comment: @Jim - Agreed, but how does that help me?

Comment: @aparente001 - This was to help establish the validity of “so yeah” and not “oh yeah” or “so year” etc.  It can also help to explain how the phrase functions.

Comment: @Jim - I see.  I wasn't thinking about validity.  Yes, that's important if I want people to answer my question!

Comment: 'Inarticulately abrupt ending'

Comment: What is it exactly you're asking? Your title says 'description', and your text asks to 'explain', but are you asking what to _call_ this phenomenon? Which one do you want (or something else)?

Comment: @Mitch - I changed "explain" to "describe."  Is that clearer?

Comment: This sounds like it should have been categorized under one of those ancient rhetorical figures of speech, that are sometimes considered errors and sometimes considered purposeful. This is like trailing off, not finishing a narrative, or being infelicitous in ending a story. What that label might be... [I don't know](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/)

Comment: @Mitch It's extremely common these days in the U.S., and not just among children, teens and young adults.  And it isn't taken as trailing off -- it's taken as signalling being done talking on the given topic.

Comment: I really think simply 'filler" is the term you're looking for.  Same with "umm", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some data to show the usage of *"and yeah"* as well as *"so yeah"*. I do agree with your conclusion that the speaker in context would most probably have used the above, as opposed to year.

[image]

Anecdotally, such phrases are actually common amongst a variety of languages and not just the US. I digress.

These phrases can be called ***fillers***. Fillers are used in informal registers. In informal registers, it is common for speakers to use informal language such as *so yeah* / *and yeah*. There isn't a clear-cut agreed upon way to determine the formality of a register but we can look at a few things. Here is just a VERY simplified list:

- The relationship of the participants (boss & worker vs boyfriend & girlfriend)
- The purpose of the discourse (to outline work objectives vs to determine what to eat)
- The phonetic & syntactic deviation from prescriptive language conventions (pronounciation of words, speaking "style")
- Vocabulary used (technical vs colloquial)

Concluding, depending on the context of what you wish you write (and the degree in which you are space limited) one should be easily able to link the informality of the register to your more probable interpretation of the inaudible being a filler EG:

> The informality of the register lends the inaudible word to most probably be a filler, and as such is reflected in the transcript.

Paraphrase as needed. Depending on space limitations one may also want to establish the level of formality of the register (such as through using the above points I mentioned) and then link that to the most probable outcome based on this.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Which color is which phrase?  "Filler" sounds promising, thank you.

Comment: @aparente001 if you right click the image and open in a new tab, you can see it in a much higher resolution. The red curve is for the phrase "and yeah". Do note that filler carries a specific linguistic meaning, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)

Comment: @aparente001 It would be helpful to the community if you voted on a best answer to this answered question please.

Comment: I didn't feel that my question was answered, but I wasn't very motivated to place a bounty.

Comment: @aparente001 Why do you feel that it is not answered? Is it that you think filler is not the correct concept to be exploring?

Comment: I don't think it was filler in this case.  I can see that it might be sometimes, but in this case it was a signal that the speaker was finished talking about that topic.  I think this may be the case in many other situations as well.  Imagine, "So that's what I have to say about that."

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> And he ***signed off*** with "So, yeah."

This is a common idiom for indicating being done with whatever one was doing.

> **2.** *Fig*. to quit doing what one has been doing and leave, go to bed, quit trying to do something, etc.
>  *I have to **sign off** and get to bed. See you all.*
>  *When you finally **sign off** tonight, please turn out all the lights.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by FARLAX](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sign+off)</sub>

I was originally thinking you treat this like a [***closing***/***valediction***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction), such as the *Regards* or similar that goes at the end of a letter.

There is also the notion of [***procedure words***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_word) that are used to signal when one is done talking. But those words are fairly well defined, since it is actually used in voice transmission protocols (e.g., CB radio).

Comment: *And he signed off with "So, yeah."*  This would work well if I were writing a story or a journalism article, including dialogue.  But I'm writing a persuasive argument, and I have to rebut what the author argued, starting with her misquote.  I have to explain succinctly that she converted "yeah" to "year" and then explain succinctly how the actual phrase ("so, yeah") functions in young person's transcribed paragraph.  It's that last part I need help with.

Comment: *Nobody signs off with "So, year."* Perhaps you can update your question with a sample sentence where you would like the phrase or term to be used?

Comment: There was no comma.  This distortion of the transcript, and the reasoning based on it, were not the stupidest thing the author wrote in her document *by far*. // Also, I made a mistake, see question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that he used 'and yeah' as a 'verbal [terminal punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_punctuation)' or possibly a 'weak verbal terminal punctuation'. While the full phrase does not garner any hits on google, 'terminal punctuation' is a clear enough concept that few readers should struggle with extrapolating the function to that kind of verbal filler.

> Terminal punctuation refers to the punctuation marks used to identify
>   the end of a portion of text. Terminal punctuation marks are also
>   referred to as end marks[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_punctuation) and stops.[2] In languages using the ISO
>   basic Latin alphabet, terminal punctuation marks are defined as the
>   period, the question mark, and the exclamation mark.[3][4] These
>   punctuation marks may bring sentences to a close. In their widest
>   sense, terminal punctuation marks bring any element of written text to
>   a close

Comment: I guess I could say that the colloquialism "and yeah" served as a terminal punctuation.  But I'm not sure they would understand.  Still, I hope this use of the term catches on. // What I ended up using (my deadline was yesterday): *Note: the transcript correctly recorded the student as saying “and yeah,” not “and year.”  “And yeah” signalled that he was done talking about that topic.*